What happens when touching a piece which cannot make a legal move?
Suppose in an official tournament game, White's king is in check by the Black queen. If I accidentally touch a pawn that cannot legally remove the check, how is the touch-move rule enforced? After researching, I've found conflicting answers: some sources mention a two-minute time penalty, while others suggest no penalty at all. For example, see these discussions on Reddit and Quora. What is the correct ruling, and is this a rule that varies by tournament?

If playing under FIDE laws for standard play  games you may make any legal move without penalty. Different time limits or jurisdictions, e.g. USCF, might be different, I don't know off the top of my head. When not on my phone I'll dig out the relevant FIDE sections.

To be clear: even if you accidentally touch a piece that can be moved, under FIDE rules there is no obligation to move it. Only deliberate touches are relevant. https://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/LawsOfChess.pdf Section 4.3 as quoted in Glorfindel's answer.

@JamesMartin: 4.2.2 instructs arbiters to be very aggressive in interpreting touches as "deliberate." If the arbiter cannot tell whether something was deliberate or not, the rules explicitly require them to treat it as deliberate.

Under FIDE rules

... if the player having the move deliberately touches on
the chessboard:
a. one or more of his own pieces, he must move the first piece touched which can be
moved

There is no penalty for touching a piece that can't be moved.
There is a two-minute penalty (or rather, a two-minute bonus for the opponent) when an illegal move is executed in §7.4:

a. If during a game it is found that an illegal move, including failing to meet the requirements of the promotion of a pawn or capturing the opponent’s king, has been completed, the position immediately before the irregularity shall be reinstated. ... The game shall then continue from this re-instated position.
b. After the action taken under Article 7.4.a, for the first two illegal moves by a player the arbiter shall give two minutes extra time to his opponent in each instance; ...

National rules may deviate from this, but especially 'accidental' touches as you mention, I don't think they will be punished. Where I used to play over-the-board chess, in the Netherlands, knocking over your king was a gesture that you resign. I lost track of how often that happened accidentally, especially during blitz.

Thanks. So touching a piece which can't be moved doesn't count as an illegal move. Am I right?

Correct. For a move, you need to release (at least) one of your pieces at a different square than it used to be (and press the clock), so touching something is never a move, let alone an illegal one. If you deliberately touch the wrong piece too many times during a game, the arbiter may impose some kind of penalty, but that should be very rare.
